# Why does updating an item in an array update the property of all elements? Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of elements iterated in a v-for, inside that v-for I have an input to dynamically update the value of the property. but when changing this it makes the change to all the items.

```
<tr v-for="(row, index) in form.items" :key="index">

   <input type="text" v-model="row.item.description" class="form-control">

</tr>
```

in data

```
 form : {

    items: [...]
 }
```

It only happens with items with the same identifier. the form variable is an object and inside are items that is the array that I iterate.

Comment: Can't reproduce the behavior https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/m9rnqop7/    Maybe you can show your own demo illustrating the issue

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'same identifier', but possibly all of the items with the same identifier are pointing to the same actual item, if you are just setting them equal to some item, and not creating a copy for each.